# How can I compute one day ahead returns in a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have been working on a project and I have tried to compute the log returns express in percentage over a period of time.
I have stored all the daily adjusted closing price in a panda dataframe like this:

```
{'SP500': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): 1115.0999755859375,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 1132.989990234375,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 1136.52001953125,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 1137.1400146484375,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 1141.68994140625},
 'A': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): 20.28476333618164,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 20.43492889404297,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 20.21295928955078,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 20.141132354736328,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 20.11502456665039},
 'AAL': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): 4.562869548797607,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 4.496876239776611,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 5.005957126617432,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 4.79855489730835,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 4.93996524810791},
 'AAP': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): 38.3176383972168,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 38.22296905517578,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 37.99578857421875,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 38.32709884643555,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 38.3176383972168},
 'AAPL': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): 6.471692085266113,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 6.572423458099365,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 6.583786487579346,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 6.479064464569092,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 6.467087268829346}}
```

I believe that the daily returns are defined as: in day t, the return would be the difference of log return of day t minus log return of day t-1. I have applied this line of code:

```
for i in df.columns:
     df[i] = np.log(df[i]) - np.log(df[i].shift(1))
```

I have checked and it gives me the expected result which is:
r<sub>t</sub><sup>i</sup> = ln(AdjClosingPrice)<sub>t</sub> - ln(AdjClosingPrice)<sub>t-1</sub>
for each columns:

```
{'SP500': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.015916082167126255,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.003110831966759875,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0005453718878234426,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 0.003993218354654715},
 'A': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.007375607740701007,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): -0.010921689703742743,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): -0.003559837812704636,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): -0.001297083166547086},
 'AAL': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): -0.014568725834338547,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.10724564178274565,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): -0.042313819049169865,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): 0.029043486854613887},
 'AAP': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): -0.0024737036578925675,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): -0.005961292490163306,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.008681861089003373,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): -0.0002468649409474999},
 'AAPL': {Timestamp('2009-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.015445029590123394,
  Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0017274020941329127,
  Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'): -0.0160339066767059,
  Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'): -0.001850310332141225}}
```

**My question is divided in two parts:**

1. How could I get r<sub>t+1</sub><sup>i</sup> ?

Would it be that r<sub>t+1</sub><sup>i</sup> = ln(AdjClosingPrice)<sub>t+1</sub> - ln(AdjClosingPrice)<sub>t</sub> ?

2. Do you have an idea of the loop I should make to compute it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer above and on some tests with various combinations, I was able to find the answer to the question:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = np.log(df[i].shift(-1)) - np.log(df[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the result column to the top and there will be tomorrow's result today, if that's what you're talking about. In this case, the column 'c' is shifted.
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
print(df)
df.c = df.c.shift(-1)
print(df)
```

Output print(df)

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5
```

Output df.c = df.c.shift(-1)

```
   a  b    c
0  1  1  2.0
1  2  2  3.0
2  3  3  4.0
3  4  4  5.0
4  5  5  NaN
```

Comment: With your help, I was able to get the right answer, I'll put a formal answer. Thank you a lot !